# Count the number of transactions the user had within the previous seven days

Tags: sql

I have a transactions table as source

| transaction_id | date | user_id | is_blocked | transaction_amount | transaction_category_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 02506723-1dd4-4f6b-af18-5c793f758b71 | 2022-04-30 | 97526bdd-12fa-4529-b4db-a95532ea7b6d | True | 11.17 | 2 |
| 920a00cf-91b7-41f7-b255-a0caff61d867 | 2022-04-30 | 27f043f1-0b03-4eb1-960e-6de67f06eb79 | True | 21.62 | 6 |
| cac92b31-8847-465f-ab63-0bc93cfe88e8 | 2022-04-09 | 2858b0b7-55f1-4f38-91e5-ad938ff861ab | True | 63.40 | 6 |
| 2e306f57-5c52-4e6b-8567-ef3c196b82a7 | 2022-05-30 | 3e401e63-ca5c-4ec9-ba42-9c85b1fe6c12 | True | 31.53 | 3 |
| cccb1a90-b1b8-4cff-9069-07f070e91687 | 2022-05-27 | 3fa7d28f-e8e7-4580-8117-cc6106ba9b35 | True | 89.40 | 10 |
| 02b9a570-cfc2-40bb-8703-ee895e39617b | 2022-02-27 | 0705b115-030f-4c7d-95f9-da607985f405 | True | 21.05 | 5 |
| f18f459c-02a5-487e-a722-667db7cc05d0 | 2022-05-06 | 327964a9-4e6f-4d4b-ba67-480c5af305cc | True | 23.95 | 4 |
| 77056e5d-3e5f-4538-9b19-1e905205a640 | 2022-03-02 | 2e67800b-8002-464c-b376-1331aa72af08 | True | 52.40 | 1 |
| 4b4dc3c8-c877-45e4-8472-9d7405076793 | 2022-05-22 | 54465a1c-97a0-4acb-9a58-de4356efbeea | True | 78.63 | 9 |
| 5da6fbb9-0de0-42c0-ab26-386ac611ce35 | 2022-02-27 | e17b7d98-5ed5-44a3-8319-6a7562ebb358 | True | 60.66 | 4 |
| 6f157f6e-99c1-41d4-bab8-575e151cf1d4 | 2022-03-05 | b5c58d7c-b779-449f-be9d-fa98d807a436 | True | 43.11 | 10 |
| 313b3ca5-7135-40b8-a538-2515440a4327 | 2022-04-28 | dbb70729-c52e-4ed8-9ee9-39bea1f97634 | True | 58.00 | 1 |
| 2b3325ae-e958-4c12-bfe3-1da1a1e19b8d | 2022-03-13 | 4592d896-057d-4e3b-8c2e-3bf9384092b5 |  |  |  |

I am currently using below query to count the number of transactions the user had within the seven  days

```
SELECT
   user_id,
   COUNT(*) AS 'Transaction within 7 Days',
FROM
transactions
WHERE
   timestamp BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE()
   AND DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 3 DAYS)  
GROUP BY
   user_id
```

Destination table

| transaction_id | user_id | date | Transaction within 7 Days |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ef05-4247 | becf-457e | 2020-01-01 | 0 |
| c8d1-40ca | becf-457e | 2020-01-05 | 1 |
| fc2b-4b36 | becf-457e | 2020-01-07 | 2 |
| 3725-48c4 | becf-457e | 2020-01-15 | 0 |
| 5f2a-47c2 | becf-457e | 2020-01-16 | 1 |
| 7541-412c | 5728-4f1c | 2020-01-01 | 0 |
| 3deb-47d7 | 5728-4f1c | 2020-01-12 | 0 |

I am looking to optimize the above query.Is there a way to optimize it using windows functions?

Comment: Please tag the appropriate database

Comment: Also can you please add how does the expected output should look like.

Comment: Most people here want sample table data and expected result as formatted text, not as images. (And I can't read that tiny image text.)

Comment: added the table

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
   user_id,
   COUNT(transaction_id) AS 'Transaction within 7 Days'
--   date,
--transaction_id
FROM
transactions
WHERE
   timestamp BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE()
   AND DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAYS)  
GROUP BY
   user_id
```